# To get upload and download progess percentages in S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get upload percentage progress of S3 using java. I'm trying this:

```
putObjectRequest.setGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent) {
        progressEvent.getBytesTransferred();
        double totalByteRead = 0;
        double percentage = 0;
        totalByteRead += progressEvent.getBytesTransferred();
        percentage += (totalByteRead / size) * 100;
        System.out.println("Percentage completed: " + percentage);
        if (progressEvent.getEventType() == progressEvent.getEventType()) {
            System.out.println("Completed");
        }
    }
});
s3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

I'm getting output as:

```
...
Percentage completed: 2.0119817541351908
Completed
Percentage completed: 1.4128940473756373
Completed
Percentage completed: 0.0
Completed
Percentage completed: 0.0
Completed
```

How to get proper percentage value?

Answer (score 0):

If getBytesTransferred() returns non-cumulative value - you need to store total bytes outside of listener method (now you declaring variable *totalByteRead* inside listener method, so it's redeclared to 0 every time *progressChanged* event is triggered)

Comment: @shantanusingh Why unaccept? Can you correct me if my answer is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Something to this effect
    // percentage += (totalByteRead / size) * 100;

    int arraymakerCOUNT=0;
    long partial = new Float(size / 100).longValue(); // make 1 percent
    long partial2 = partial; // partial and partial2 are 100th of file bytes size
    //
    long[] percentProgress = new long[100];
    while(arraymakerCOUNT < 100){
    if(arraymakerCOUNT==0){
    percentProgress[arraymakerCOUNT] = partial2;
    }else{
    partial += partial2; // make partial bigger by 1 percent relating file size count
    percentProgress[arraymakerCOUNT] = partial;
    }
    arraymakerCOUNT++;
    } //end while

// Above should be found when the process starts BUT percentProgress[] array should be available in scope to below

    // BELOW is for the "change listener" triggered by it or triggers a method with the listener containing its call
    int percentCheckLoop = 0; // for the index of the 100 element array containing 1 percent STEP sizes in order
    while(percentCheckLoop < 100){ // loop from 1 toward 100 percent by 1 percent at a test
    if(percentProgress[percentCheckLoop] < (new Double(totalByteRead).longValue())){
     System.out.println("Percentage completed: " + (percentCheckLoop+1);
// switch loop off after printout
    percentCheckLoop = 101; // ready the STOP loop condition
    }
    percentCheckLoop++;
    } // end while
```